# Installing UrQMD in Linux Mint gives error after make command

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, fortran

I am using Linux Mint 21 Cinammon to install the UrQMD simulation package. I have ROOT installed as well as all the required dependencies as specified by the [webpage](https://urqmd.org/). The instructions say:

```
$ tar -xvf urqmd-3.4.tar
$ make
```

After the make command, I get

```
    if [ -e lhc ]; then patch -R -p0 < lhc.patch || true; fi
rm -f lhc
gfortran -O3 -mcmodel=medium -c make22.f -o obj_x86_64/make22.o
make22.f:548:72:

  548 |  151        ba2(j)=0d0
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 151 at (1)
make22.f:3593:72:

 3593 |  152  ba2(j)=p(2,j)/p(2,4)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 152 at (1)
make22.f:1644:45:

 1644 |          call getbran((/sig1,sig2,sig3/),1,3,dummy,1,3,channel)
      |                                             1
......
 3739 |       call getbran(x,minnuc,maxmes,xmax,im,ip,ir)
      |                                   2          
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (INTEGER(4)/REAL(8)).
make22.f:1670:39:
```

I suspect it has to do with the version of gfortran since it's recommended to use 6 or below as the software hasn't been updated in some time. I also tried to install an older version of gfortran and gcc but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue a few days ago and it was indeed an issue with the gfortran version. In the extracted file for the program there's a folder called mk that contains the file "Linux.mk". The first lines of the file are as follows:

```
# We need to define a fortran compiler $(FC) and a linker $(LD).
 FC = gfortran
 LD = $(FC)
```

Changing it to

```
 FC = gfortran-6
 LD = $(F77)
```

Solved the problem. I installed gfortran-6 previously and have it alongside gfortran-11.